# Backwards-compatible setOnDateSetListener

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, datepickerdialog

I'm trying to use a `DatePickerDialog` in a `Fragment` and set an `OnDateSetListener` to it, but when I try using the `setOnDateSetListener` method I get a compile-time warning like *Call requires API level 24 (current min is 16)*.
Is there an alternative way I can receive this callback?
My app's min SDK is 16 and the max is 26.

Here's my code:

```
DatePickerDialog.Builder builder = new DatePickerDialog.Builder(getContext());
builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_date);
builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, this);
DatePickerDialog dialogue = (DatePickerDialog) builder.create();
dialogue.setOnDateSetListener(this); // This is where I get the error
dialogue.show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this constructor for DatePickerDialog

```
DatePickerDialog(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
```

Answer (score 1):

`DatePickerDialog(Context context)` constructor was added in API level 24.

If you want to make it backwards compatible, use [this constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int)) which was added in API level 1:

```
DatePickerDialog (Context context, 
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, 
                int year, 
                int month, 
                int dayOfMonth)
```